# workaround for error: Bad CPU type in executable c

Tags: r, sequence-alignment

I use clustal() from library ape every now and then, but now it doesnt work...

code:

```
sylvia.clus = clustal(sylvia.seq)
```

Error:

```
> sh: /opt/X11/bin/clustalw2: Bad CPU type in executable cannot open
> file
> '/var/folders/46/vt_whvms133190kjmlx5gf4m0000gn/T//Rtmpa82i72/clustald5d11dadcdf.fas':
> No such file or directoryError in file(con, "rb") : cannot open the
> connection
```

Is there any workaround? (I try reinstalling ape library, but I got the same error)

Screenshot from Rstudio:
[image]

Comment: Did you recently update the OS on your mac? Try opening running `xcode-select --install` and try your code again after you run that.

Comment: Also you could just open the XCode app on the Mac - it will "install additional components" and then your code might work fine. I do see that there was a recent update.

Comment: I get the error in Rstudio (I added screenshot).

Comment: I ran:    xcode-select --install   in the terminal and I get 'xcode-select: error: command line tools are already installed, use "Software Update" to install updates'

Comment: Did you try opening XCode the app?

Comment: re-install ape and clustalw?